# Is there any option to export database structure including Data from apex.oracle.com

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a workspace on https://apex.oracle.com, and want to export my schema including data. where can i find the option?

Answer (score 1):

There's none, as far as I can tell. You can export an application (and get the .SQL file as a result), but for tables and data stored within, there's no simple export option.

However, if you go to SQL Workshop and then to Utilities, you'll see

- `Generate DDL` option which lets you choose what you want to *export*; file you save can be found in the Script Repository
- `Data Workshop` lets you *export* data as text or XML

Once you have DDL script, you can create objects in the target schema. Then load data you exported (using, for example, SQL*Loader). That's not a simple task, especially if there are many tables used in your application.

Didn't you agree (when applying for a free workspace on apex.oracle.com) that you'll use it for testing/educational purposes? Developing a *serious* application there probably isn't the best option you could have chosen.